# Rcpp: one function works on NumericVector, the other needs to treat it as scalar

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have two functions written with Rcpp.

The first function `f` takes a NumericVector as input and returns a NumericVector as output. But often, `f` is meant to be treated as a scalar function. When I call it from R, it doesn't matter, since R will treat any scalar as a vector anyways, so I don't have to bother about it. I can both use `f` as a scalar or a vector function, e.g. `f(1)` and `f(c(1,2,3,4)` both work.

1. Question 1: Is this a bad idea? Should I make TWO separate functions, one scalar, and one vectorized? For example, is there some unwanted overhead when I call `f` from R using scalar input rather than a vector?

The second function `g` needs to use `f` purely as a scalar function. This causes a problem because I need to call `f` from Rcpp when I am defining `g`.... now I can't use it as a scalar function by calling `f(x`) for some double x.

I tried doing something like this from inside the definition of `g`:

```
NumericVector x = NumericVector::create(value); //create vector of length 1
f(x) //use f(x) as scalar
```

but timing the code took absurdly long (since the function `g` needs to perform the above operation many times).

1. Question 2: Is there a way to more quickly treat `f` as a scalar function just like I would if I was in R?

My current solution is to do what I asked in Queston 1: create another `f` function which is scalar, and then call THAT one from `g`, so that inside `g` we simply say

```
alternative_f(x) //use alternative f as scalar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could factor out the  scalar code into a separate (inline) function and call that from both `f` (with `std::transform`) and `g` (+ additional logic). Simplified example:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

inline double f_impl (double x) {
    return x * 2;
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double g (double x) {
    return f_impl(x) + 2;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector f (Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector y(Rcpp::no_init(x.length()));
    std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), f_impl);
    return y;
}
```

Comment: what does no_init do here?

Comment: @malikjohnson It inhibits initialization of the vector's elements to zero.